# 'rails s' command is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Running `rails s` shows the following error.

```
$ rails s

Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options] 
Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]           # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                              # Default: /usr/bin/ruby2.3
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]   # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db)
                              # Default: sqlite3
  -b, [--builder=BUILDER]     # Path to an application builder (can be a filesystem path or URL)
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]   # Path to an application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--dev]                 # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge]                # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
      [--skip-gemfile]        # Don't create a Gemfile
  -O, [--skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record files
  -T, [--skip-test-unit]      # Skip Test::Unit files
  -J, [--skip-prototype]      # Skip Prototype files
  -G, [--skip-git]            # Skip Git ignores and keeps
Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet]    # Supress status output
  -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist
Rails options:
  -v, [--version]  # Show Rails version number and quit
  -h, [--help]     # Show this help message and quit
Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.
Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog
    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
    See the README in the newly created application to get going.
```

How to rectify this issue? Please give some ideas on why this issue occurs.

Comment: You are running this command from the directory that does not contain rails project.

Comment: If you created a project then type `cd project_name` then rails s or rails server

Answer (score 1):

Issue is you running this wrong directory e.g project creating command

```
rails new project_name
```

Then

```
cd project_name
```

Then run for bundle, rake, & server

```
rails s
```

or

```
 rails server
```

Comment: Its not working/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:272: warning: circular argument reference - now
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:116:in `railties': uninitialized constant Rails::Application::Railties (NameError)
 from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:180:in `initializers'
 from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-

Comment: Run `bundle install` then run server